# How to have an Ubuntu installed first, then have a Hidden Windows Operating System?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, multi-boot, truecrypt

How to have an Ubuntu installed first, then have a Hidden Windows Operating System using TrueCrypt or something else?

I have tried twice, but just didn't come up with what I'm expecting. Currently, I had both, but Windows is not Hidden.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it right, a simple solution could be installing Windows in virtualbox and storing the virtual disk on the encrypted volume.

Comment: @ laurent : Yeah, I think u got what I mean. What I am into is to have my main OS (which is Ubuntu) everytime I boot my laptop, then I would also like to have a Windows Operating System (but Hidden), which means, I will have to enter some passwords before having it running. How can I do that?Can I just install my Windows 8 inside my external hard disk? How to do that?